# How to convert a date as year/week to the first day of the week via POSIXct?

Tags: r, posixct

I want to convert

```
myDate=as.character("2017/02")
```

which is in the format year/week to a date that is the first day of this week. So I tried:

```
print(as.POSIXct(myDate,format="%Y/%U"))
```

However, this gives me

```
[1] "2017-05-03 CEST"
```

which is certainly **not** the first day of the second week in 2017.

**Question**: How do I need to change `as.POSIXct(myDate,format="%Y/%U")` in order to make it work as described above?

Comment: Possibly related to http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Convert-201248-to-Year-Week-date-format-in-R-td4654068.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A year and a week is not a proper date.  A day would need to be associated with the week.  For example:

```
myDate=as.character("2017/02")    
as.POSIXct(paste(myDate, "0"),format="%Y/%U %w")

#[1] "2017-01-08 EST"
```

this assumes the first day of the week is Sunday.  If you prefer a Monday then see the %u option.

Answer (score 1):

Here a possible approach:

```
myDate=as.character("2017/02")
```

Creation of the calendar (yyyy/dd/mm) of indicated year (E.g. 2017)

```
year_date<-seq.Date(as.Date(paste0(substr(myDate,1,4),"/01/01")),as.Date(paste0(substr(myDate,1,4),"/12/31")),by=1)
```

Using library `ISOweek`, this code finds the first day of each week

```
library("ISOweek")
first_day<-cumsum(ISOweekday(year_date)==1)
```

Extraction of the first day of the indicated week

```
year_date[which(first_day==as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(myDate,split="/"))[2]))[1]]
[1] "2017-01-09"
```

**NB**: in this example weeks start on monday