# Is it possible to convert year-week date format to the first day of the week`?

Tags: r

I have a Year-Week format date. Is it possible to convert it to the first day of the week i.e. `201553` is `2015-12-28` and `201601` is `2016-01-04`.
I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50155460/how-to-convert-a-date-as-year-week-to-the-first-day-of-the-week-via-posixct) how to do it, however, it does not work correctly on my dates. Could you help to do it without `ISOweek` package.

```
date<-c(201553L, 201601L, 201602L, 201603L, 201604L, 201605L, 201606L, 
201607L, 201608L, 201609L)
as.POSIXct(paste(date, "0"),format="%Y%u %w")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way,

```
date<-data.frame(first = c(201553L, 201601L, 201602L, 201603L, 201604L, 201605L, 201606L, 
        201607L, 201608L, 201609L))
```

First separate the `week` and `year` from integer,

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
date = date %>% mutate(week = str_sub(date$first,5,6))
date = date %>% mutate(year = str_sub(date$first,1,4))
```

The use `aweek` package to find the date,

```
library(aweek)
date = date %>% mutate(actual_date = get_date(week = date$week, year = date$year))

    first week year   actual_date 
1  201553   53 2015    2015-12-28
2  201601   01 2016    2016-01-04
3  201602   02 2016    2016-01-11
4  201603   03 2016    2016-01-18
5  201604   04 2016    2016-01-25
6  201605   05 2016    2016-02-01
7  201606   06 2016    2016-02-08
8  201607   07 2016    2016-02-15
9  201608   08 2016    2016-02-22
10 201609   09 2016    2016-02-29
```